# In a big OpenGL game with lots of 3D moving objects, how are the points typically updated?

Tags: opengl, 3d

1. Points calculated with own physics engine and then sent to OpenGL every time it has to display, e.g. with glBufferSubDataArb, with the updated coordinates of a flying barrel
2. There are lots of barrels with the same world coordinates but somehow for each one you tell OpenGL to use a different matrix transformation. When a barrel moves you update it's transformation matrix somehow, to reflect which way it rotated/translated in the world.
3. Some other way

Also, if the answer is #2, is there any easy way to do it, e.g. with abstracted code rather than manipulating the matrices yourself

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OpenGL is not a scene graph, it's a drawing API. Most recent versions of OpenGL (OpenGL-3 core and above) reflect this, by not managing matrix state at all. Indeed the answer is 2, more or less. And actually you are expected to deal with the matrix math. OpenGL-3 no longer provides any primitives for that.

Usually a physics engine sees an object as a rigid body with a convex hull. The natural way to represent such a body is using a 4×3 matrix (a 3×3 rotation matrix and a translation vector). So if using a physics engine you're presented with such matrices anyway.

Also you must understand that OpenGL doesn't maintain a scene, so there is nothing you "update". You just draw your data using OpenGL. Matrices are loaded as they are needed.